# Using an earth bonding plug for grounding server rack enclosure

Tags: rack

Can an [Earth Bonding Plug](http://sg.element14.com/multicomp/070-0011/earth-bonding-plug-uk-3x10mm/dp/1687854) be used to connect a server rack enclosure for the purposes of electrical grounding from a safety perspective?

I've read [How do I ground a network switch?](https://serverfault.com/questions/582627/how-do-i-ground-a-network-switch/582645) (among other articles on rack grounding). Can the wall power socket be used together with an earth bonding plug for the same purpose?

Answer (score 0):

This is question for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/
You should ground entire rack cabinets, and then connect additional wire (if exists) from enclosure to cabinet.
If you use power from wall socket, then device is grounded by power wire, so using an earth bonding plug have low sense.
You relay need grounding rack cabinets if you have an electric connection from/to rack cabinet or: use an ups, rack power distribution, automatic transfer switches or other power distribution unit.
it is relay not recommended to use earth bonding plug to ground cabinets. Grounding should be permanent.